# Unable to destructure Functor(Module)

Tags: ocaml, reason

This syntax would be very useful—is there a reason for this not working? Thanks!

```
module Foo = {
  let bar: string = "bar"
};

let bar = Foo.bar; /* works */
let { bar } = Foo; /* Unbound record field bar */
```

[Try it online!](https://reasonml.github.io/try.html?reason=LYewJgrgNgpgBAMRCOBeOBvAUHOsAucARgIYBOAXHAM75kCWAdgOZpwBEpZ7WAvgNxYsBYuTZIQAOi784AegBUcAO4gyAa2pwFc4TEIZRZOL3HJZiuAFVGREBEZg4ZGAGM1TgGb0YUJ1205IA)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The closest you can do is something like this:

```
module Foo = {
  let bar = "bar";
  let baz = "baz";
};

let (bar, baz) = Foo.(bar, baz);
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to destructure a module in OCaml/Reason.

The equivalent OCaml code produces a syntax error on line 3

```
module Foo = struct let bar: string = "bar" end
let bar = Foo.bar
let struct bar end = Foo

File "", line 3, characters 4-10: Error: Syntax error
```

---

If you are OK with bringing *all* of the values specified in Foo into the local scope, then you can use `open Foo`. 
https://reasonml.github.io/try.html?reason=LYewJgrgNgpgBAMRCOBeOBvOsAucBGAhgE4BccAzjsQJYB2A5mnAERHEtwC+A3AFAgADjDqJk-AFIUAdFBAMAFOwCUQA

```
module Foo = { let bar: string = "bar" };
open Foo;
Js.log(bar)
```

If you also want to export all of the definitions in Foo through the current modules exports, you can `include Foo`.
https://reasonml.github.io/try.html?reason=LYewJgrgNgpgBAMRCOBeOBvOsAucBGAhgE4BccAzjsQJYB2A5mnAERHEtwC+A3AFD0AxlAhh4SEPwBSFAHRQQDABTsAlEA

```
module Foo = { let bar: string = "bar" };
include Foo;
Js.log(bar)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this up 